# Single Linkage Clustering using Java

Tags: java, cluster-analysis

I want to make a program using Java that can do Single Linkage Clustering for some data. The program mechanism is as follows:
I can input some data to the program and number of cluster that I want. Then the program will give the member of that cluster.

Is there anyone can help? I don't know where to start.
Thank you

Example:
Input data: 2, 8, 10, 13, 17, 20, 34, 38, 53
Number of cluster: 3
Result:

> Cluster 1: 2, 8, 10, 13, 17, 20
> Cluster 2: 34, 38
> Cluster 3: 53

Comment: Sounds like you might no be familiar with Java. I would suggest you to follow a tutorial or a begginers book (I recommend Head First Java).